# Few main() methods in one java package

Tags: java

I suddenly wonder that what's the difference between creating multiple main methods ,and creating one main method in a java package.

Example 1, An a.java has its main method, then the a.java method will pass some to the b.java that also has its main method.

A.java ( A.java's main method ) --(Passing some to)--> B.java (B.Java's main method )

Example 2, Not like the above, the a.java does Not have its main method but b.java only HAS its main method. Run the b.java to get some from the a.java .

Run B.java (This only has its main method) --(To get some from ) --> A.java (It does Not have its main method )

I think this is complicated to explain as text... I just want to know that what is the difference between them , and if you recommend either one of them, which one would be good ?

Comment: It took you longer to type this question than it would have taken to try it. A program has one [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that if you implement `main()` in multiple classes, then you'll have the option of running each individual class as a Java application.

Do you want or need to do this?  If so, there's your answer.

Otherwise (and more typically), you have a single class that implements `main()`, and it interacts with or delegates to other classes by directly invoking their declared methods (which, if you're using good coding style, will be descriptively named and *not* called `main()`).

In short, implement `main()` when you want your class to be directly runnable as a Java application.  Otherwise, don't.

Whether you have zero, one, or more than one classes implemeting `main()` is up to your requirements, though in most cases you'll either have zero or one.

Also note that your scope is not limited to a single package.  There's nothing that says that each package should or must have a class that implements `main()`.  In fact, most packages have none, and adding `main()` implementations purely to satisfy a "there should always be at least one" kind of rule would be a bad idea.

If your requirements don't call for a `main()` implementation, don't add one.

Comment: Thank you !! This is what I have been looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping two main methods does not make any sense. It is like you are using one main method as it is and other main as a simple method. The only thing here is the name is main(). You can set its name other than this as well. But in class A you need the main method.

Comment: Thanks.I understood.however I am still a bit confused. when I read other source that has few main methods separately like open new frames,and call another class to excuse db things..